# Юнити не отображает текст

Tags: c#, unity3d, текст

начала изучать юнити самостоятельно, столкнулась с проблемой что не могу поставить текст в юнити, просто не хочет его отображать, а следовательно не получается с ним работать. Выдает ошибку, я не знаю что делать, помогите пожалуйста[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скорее всего дело в самом Юнити он считает что его же текст с ошибкой. Попробуй скачать новый фонт (шрифт) и всё должно заработать

Comment: Это значит что в TMPro шрифт не задан.